# О «гражданской жене» и «институте брака»

Tags: синонимы, терминология

Среди фундаментальных отличий человека от животного — по определению о. Димитрия (Смирнова): разума, слова, совести, веры, брака — есть два признака: брак (семья) и совесть (стыд), и связывающая их заповедь «Не прелюбодействуй».
В последние лет восемьдесят правовой статус в отношении пары *на словах* присваивается сторонам, часто ни прошедшим регистрации брака, ни расторгнувшим прежний — официальный. Происходит путаница, — все они, наряду с вступившими в брак по закону, охотно называются гражданскими супругами:

> Ну то есть вы просто живете, или ты живешь как невеста или уже как гражданская жена, причем важно не то, как ты это воспринимаешь... [Новые родственники ― как уживаемся? (2008)]

> Мужа закрыли в сизо, я гражданская жена. Куда обращаться, чтобы стать его общественным защитником? [Общественный защитник (2010-2012)]

> Помимо Матильды Ивановны у Вовы была еще одна гражданская жена ― двадцатипятилетняя медсестра отделения ухо-горло-носа Катя, очень красивая и работящая женщина. [В. Михальский. Весна в Карфагене (2001)]

> Причем мужчины у нее были, и даже один гражданский муж, Борис навел предварительно справки. [Елена Белкина. От любви до ненависти (2002)]

И то, что порой трудно разобраться, о чём идёт речь, и то, что авторы преимущественно отвергают штатных «любовников» и «сожителей», принижая другое, выше стоящее слово, приводит к вопросу: есть ли в арсенале языка другие, приемлемые для совестливых сограждан уместные термины?

Answer (score 4):

В первую очередь, не могу не заметить, что браки без регистрации существуют не "последние лет восемьдесят", а чуть ли не с самой зари цивилизации. Определенные законы вводились преимущественно для защиты от насильственных союзов и, по наитию, для поддержания разнообразия генофонда, но как такового требования регистрации почти никогда не существовало.

Греко-римляне позже ввели требования моногамии, предположительно для поддержания демократии и равенства, что впоследствии и позаимствовало большинство авраамических сект, включая раннее христианство.

Непосредственно требования к проведению неких санкционированных процедур регистрации существовали преимущественно для высших сословий, как правило для бюрократических целей ведения учета членов крупных семей и упрощения отслеживания процессов наследства и несения ответственности по закону (в отдельные периоды, мужья наделялись полным контролем над женами и несли за них ответственность перед законом).

Распространение церковных\государственных браков произошло уже в конце первого (начале второго) тысячелетия нашей эры в Восточной Римской империи и ближе к концу средних веков в Европейских странах.

Это я всё к тому, что официальная регистрация браков, на самом деле, сравнительно молодой институт в контексте истории развития человеческой цивилизации, поэтому использование термина "гражданский супруг" вполне уместно.

Что касается непосредственно альтернатив, то мировой практикой является использование слова "партнер", как нейтрального термина обозначающего участника гражданского союза.

Также, распространено использование понятия "вторая половина", однако, это зачастую применимо и к участникам романтических отношений не заключающих брака (будь то государственный брак, контрактный брак, церковный брак, брак со свидетелями, или брак по сожительству).

Comment: За ответ спасибо, вижу его в последних двух фразах. Первой части (о всеобщей истории) могло бы и не быть: речь именно о положении дел в России и  русском языке. Судя по примерам из НКРЯ сдвиг произошёл с крахом мперии: https://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E3%F0%E0%E6%E4%E0%ED%F1%EA%E0%FF%20%E6%E5%ED%E0&p=1. P.S. Венчание, церковный брак т.е., к романтическим отношениям причислять нельзя.